# Ansible template module not parsing with_items variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am using a simple template with only variables in it.
This is how my task looks like in my playbook (actually a role being used from my playbook):

```
- name: Ensure the conf file exists
  template:
    src: file.conf.j2
    dest: '/opt/file.conf'
  with_items: '{{ myrole }}'
```

I keep variables in group_vars. Any variable in `file.conf.j2` will be expanded correctly, like `{{ myrole_user }}` but fails when expanding one of with_items variables, like `{{ myrole.applicationName }}`.

My group_vars looks like this:

```
myrole_user: regularuser
myrole:
  -  { applicationName: foo, othervar: bar }
```

And this is the Ansible error:

> "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'list object' has no attribute 'applicationName'"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You defined a list called `myrole` and then try to access a value of the key `myrole.applicationName`, so you get an error message that the list does not contain the key/attribute (which is true -- a list contains only an ordered set of elements).

Ansible `with_` loops by default<sup>*</sup> set a variable named `item` containing the value of the element in the current iteration, so in the template you should refer to the `item` (not to the `myrole` variable which remains intact):

```
{{ item.applicationName }}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> you can change this with `loop_var` setting in the [loop control](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control) section.